# Help with basic high school math. What happens to $j^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, complex-numbers, factoring

I know my math is very rusty, actually, it has always been that way. but I need help with this. The question below has me stumped. I've tried to show the steps I went through to get the answer. Please tel me where I made the mistake.

---

If $x=a$ and $x=b$ are two roots of a quadratic equation, then $(x-a)(x-b) = 0$ gives the quadratic equation.

That is$$(x - a)(x - b) = x^2 - (a + b)x + ab = 0.$$

Here, the two roots are $x= -2 + j\sqrt5$ and $x = -2 - j\sqrt5$ so that$$(x – [-2 + j\sqrt5])(x – [-2 - j\sqrt5]) = 0.$$

That is$$x^2 - x[-2 + j\sqrt5 - 2 - j\sqrt5] + [-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = 0.$$

I understand that
\begin{gather*}
x^2 - x[-2 + j\sqrt5 - 2 - j\sqrt5] + [-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = 0\\
x^2 - x[-2 - 2] + [-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = 0\\
x^2 - x[-4] + [-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = 0\\
x^2 + 4x + [-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = 0.
\end{gather*}

if we separate out the last term for simplicity:
\begin{align*}
[-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] & = (-2)(-2) + (-2)(-j\sqrt5) + (-2)(+j\sqrt5) + (+j\sqrt5)(-j\sqrt5)\\
& = 4 + (2j\sqrt5) - (2j\sqrt5) +(-j\sqrt5)^2\\
& = 4 + (2j\sqrt5) - (2j\sqrt5) +(-j^2)(-\sqrt5)^2\\
& = 4 +j^2 5
\end{align*}

Putting this last term back into the main equation results in$$x^2 + 4x + (4+j^2 5) = 0.$$

In the book ([Advanced Engineering Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0831134496))* this equation works out to$$x^2 + 4x + 9 = 0.$$

**What I don’t understand is what happened to $j^2$**. How does it just magically disapear?

*If you use the Amazon "Look inside" feature you can see it on page 4.

Comment: The last line in the sequence of equations after "if we seperate put the last term for simplicity" should be $4-j^25$, as $(-j^2)(-\sqrt{5})^2=-j^25$. This gives us $4-5j^2=4-(-1)\cdot 5=9$, because $j=\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: You made a mistake,
$$(-2+j\sqrt{5})(-2-j\sqrt{5})=4-5j^2$$

Comment: You have to be careful with signs: $(-j)(+j) = -j^2$ is not the same as $(-j)^2$.

Comment: As the son of an electrical engineer, I learned to use the letter $j$ for $\sqrt{-1}$ before I learned to use $i$.  Here's something that's happened to me several times with undergraduates.  I'm doing some routine calculation in which $i^2$ appears, and a student show claims to be well aware of the fact that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ does not know what $i^2$ is.  I ask if they know what $\sqrt{83}\cdot\sqrt{83}$ is, and they say: not without a calculator.  I ask: Do you know what square roots are?  They say "yes".  Then I say $\sqrt{83}\cdot\sqrt{83}$ is $83$.  Then I'm asked how I got that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy $*$ *shudder* $*$

Comment: @anon You think that's bad? As the son of an Econ professor, I hear way worse. The one that takes the cake is a student asking for a calculator on an exam to simplify $\frac{120}{1}$.

Comment: @Gineer: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123652/multiplying-exponents-with-variables-inside) of Arturo Magidin might help you get the signs correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are your steps with mistakes highlighted in red:

$[-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = (-2)(-2) + (-2)(-j\sqrt5) + (-2)(+j\sqrt5) + (+j\sqrt5)(-j\sqrt5)$
$= 4 + (2j\sqrt5) - (2j\sqrt5) + \color{red}{(-j\sqrt5)^2}$
$ = 4 + (2j\sqrt5) - (2j\sqrt5) + \color{red}{(-j^2)(-\sqrt5)^2}$
$ = 4 + \color{red}{j^2 5}$

Here is fixed, with highlighting in red:

$[-2 + j\sqrt5][-2 - j\sqrt5] = (-2)(-2) + (-2)(-j\sqrt5) + (-2)(+j\sqrt5) + \color{blue}{(+j\sqrt5)(-j\sqrt5)}$
$= 4 + (2j\sqrt5) - (2j\sqrt5) +\color{red}{(-1)\times j^2\times (\sqrt5)^2}$
$ = 4 + (2j\sqrt5) - (2j\sqrt5) +\color{red}{(-1)\times (-1)\times 5}$
$ = 4 +\color{red}{5} = 9$

Note that

$$\color{blue}{(+j\sqrt5)(-j\sqrt5)} =
\color{red}{(-1)\times j^2\times (\sqrt5)^2}$$

and

$$j^2 = -1$$